# Devise on ginjo-rfm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, filemaker

I'm using the ginjo-RFM gem for connecting to a Filemaker Database, and want to use Devise for authentication. The problem with this is the fact that Devise requires my User model to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base - and RFM requires, for it to access the database at all, to inherit from Rfm::Base. Is it possible to let my User class inherit from both Rfm::Base and ActiveRecord::Base?

**User.rb** (model)

```
class User < Rfm::Base
require 'rfm'
rolify
config :layout => 'XXXXXX' #Connecting Rails to the FileMaker layout
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

This will fail 'cause devise relies on ActiveRecord::Base and vice versa. Any ideas?

**Ginjo-rfm:** http://rubygems.org/gems/ginjo-rfm

**Devise:** https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise actually relies on [orm_adapter](https://github.com/ianwhite/orm_adapter) rather than directly on ActiveRecord. (Take a look [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/lib/devise/orm).) So in theory, it would be trivial to use Devise with any class that has an OrmAdapter implemented.

Since [ginjo-rfm implements ActiveModel](https://github.com/ginjo/rfm#data-modeling-with-activemodel), it probably wouldn't be too difficult to write an OrmAdapter for it. (Look at the [ActiveRecord OrmAdapter](https://github.com/ianwhite/orm_adapter/blob/master/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb) - it almost fits on one screen.)

To summarize my approach:

1.Write an OrmAdapter for ginjo-rfm (and hopefully open-source it as a gem!).

2.Then add the following to your application (or release it as a gem so others can benefit):

```
require 'orm_adapter/adapters/rfm'

Rfm::Base.extend Devise::Models
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like more of a solution(!!!). I'm not particularly experienced with writing orm-adapters, but I'm sure I'll figure it out. I'm guessing I want to write the orm-adapter to `lib/devise/orm/`, right? I'm also guessing that I have to adapt my database structure to one thats compatible with what Devise requires, right? Again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I've never written one either! :) But thankfully it looks pretty easy to do. I'll add some information on my suggested approach. Re: schema, yes, your life will be easier if you adapt your database structure to match Devise.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to create a new class that you can delegate the filemaker calls to.

The User class is how they auth to your website, and you manage roles.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

end
```

The FileMakerUser class is for accessing Filemaker

```
class FileMakerUser < Rfm::Base
 require 'rfm'
 config :layout => 'XXXXXX' #Connecting Rails to the FileMaker layout
 # other filemaker stuff
end
```

You could use a file_maker_user? column in user to signify that they have a filemaker account. (if that made sense, like if not all users of your web app have to have filemaker accounts in order to use the system)

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is possibly a solution. All my users are going to have a :username and :password already existing in the filemaker database, and I'm unsure if Devise can refer to my FM-tables for authentication. How would you go about writing a logic for this? Remember that the username and password already exist in my FM database.